# Cursor moving to the end of the formula bar in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sometimes when I try to edit a formula in excel and I press shift, backspace,  etc. the cursor jumps to the end of the formula bar.  This is obviously very frustrating, but it also means sometimes I can't even add an open parentheses unless I am writing the formula for the first time.   Anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Silly question, have you ruled out this being a hardware (keyboard) issue?

Comment: I actually didn't even think about that!  If it's not an issue anyone else has ever had I'll swap out the keyboard and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Another clue that it may not be an Excel issue, but hardware, would be if that issue occurs in any other program/application